# Gradle sync failed: Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available

Tags: android, gradle, build

My project was running perfectly fine 2 days ago and when i came back to it, i get this error when the gradle sync happens:

```
Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
    https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
    https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
Required by:
    project :mobile > gradle.plugin.nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.12.1
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried:

- Updating Android Studio
- Invalidating caches in Android Studio
- Starting from a fresh git cloned copy of my project

Some settings you might be interested in:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Can you please post the entire app.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar issue and assume it's due to this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment30